# Unity 3D:access to Unity 3D API from C/C++ code

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine

Now, I have resource-consuming C# script, uses Unity API. If I try to write external library (due to performance reasons), can I access Unity3D API from C/C++ code (e.g. *Physics.OverlapSphere* or *Physics.SphereCast* functions)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot. The Unity3d classes are only accessible to C# code.
C++ plugins cannot call Unity3d functions. The only exception are rendering plugins, as described in [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/NativePluginInterface.html).

As a aside: The Physics functions are likely heavily optimized in the Unity engine, so if the main cost of your resource-consuming script comes from the usage of these functions, the gain would be minimal or even negative due to the need of marshalling the data for passing them to the C++ plugin and back. You can check this using the script profiler is you have the Pro version.

As another aside, you will likely get faster and better answers on https://answers.unity3d.com/, the dedicated Q&A site for Unity.

Comment: @andreas, my script will use Physics.* functions inside of for-loop, with up to 100K iterations. Hmm, now I'll try to optimize my c# code.

Comment: If you're calling those functions 100k times *per frame* you might find yourself in difficulty: that's 3 million calls *per second* at 30fps.

Comment: Dan, this is true. lewis, in this case, you should really try and see if there are other, less computationally intensive ways of achieving what you want.

Comment: @DanPuzey I'm try to realize some _cell-automation_ algorythm, and external influence tp it's cells. _Cell_ _automata_ implemented in plane's mesh, and quads (triangle pairs) are cells. Influence area implemented by Cylinder object's radius. Now, I need to find all cells than affected by influence (in Unity - plane's mesh triangles, overlaps by Cylinder).

Comment: @lewis, do you really need to repeat the calculation of the influence area each frame? If not, you could do this once and save the results for the following calculations.

Comment: @anderas. User may move influence area on the plane, therefore i need to recalculate affected cells. May be, I will recalculate cells once per second, not in every frame. And I think, I need to divide my plane to big _metaquads_ (containing many triangles), and first check this metaquads to affecting. By this action, I'll determine affected metaquads (so approximately affected triangles), and eliminate unnecessary triangles calculation.